# Exception from code syntax highlighting in listings

Tags: listings, verbatim

**EDIT**: The question is not really relevant for me any more, I decided to instead use the `highlight` package in `R` to export Code as LaTeX output. This still requires manual modifications, but at least I could get it to work. Maybe the question could still be kept open and "unanswered" in case anyone comes up with a solution.

I am using the listings package to include some R code into LaTeX. Now, some R functions like `date()` or `start` are highlighted (in blue). However, some of my variables, unfortunately include strings like date or start. I would like that only the functions are highlighted, but not the stuff in the variable names. For example in the following code, only the `date` in the first line should be highlighted

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
  language=R,                     % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=none,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{darkgray},   % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},      % string literal style
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
a <- date(123)
date.a <- 123
a.start <- 456
a_start <- 456
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to exclude the other apparences of `date`, or general apparences of `start` from the highlighting?
I tried adding a `deletekeywords={start}` option to `\lstset`, but it does not change the output

In case there is no such option, I would also be happy to remove any highlighting of `date` or `start` at all, but the `deletekeywords={start}` option does not seem to do the job.

Further, I tried the command with which "." and "_" can be added to the list of letters, but that didn't change anything as well. Maybe some weird interaction. I found a completely other solution instead, and now use the `highlight` package directly in `R`. Not really an elegant solution, but at least I could get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `listings`' definition of `R` (in `lstlang3.sty`) we find:

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},%
alsoother={._$},%
```

You see that `_` is both a keyword itself and has category code other. Also `.` has category code other. If we undo this, i.e., remove the keyword (which for keywords defined with `otherkeywords` apparently means we [have to set the whole list anew but without the keyword we want removed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186092/)) and assign both characters to be letters

```
alsoletter={._},
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,/} %$
```

then you get the desired output. With `.` and `_` being letters `listings` won't consider `start` or `date` as functions in the variables names because it now considers the whole string `date.a` (including `.`) as one word:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  language=R,                     % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=none,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},  % choose the background color. You must
                                % add \usepackage{color}
  columns=fullflexible,
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{darkgray},   % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},      % string literal style
  alsoletter={._},
  otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,/}
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
a <- date(123)
date.a <- 123
a.start <- 456
a_start <- 456
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks. Also much better than my "solution" of using the highlight package in R to export the code. In the meantime, I have gone on to using Sweave / knitr, which I thought was complicated to use, but turned out to be quite straightforward and produces nice results