# How to set style for comments in listings (SAS language)?

Tags: listings

Premise: I have to use ShareLaTeX (or Overleaf) because I can't install anything on the computer I'm working with.

I'm writing a document with a lot of SAS code snippets, I'm using `minted` and I'm quite content of the result, but I would like to add some more keywords to the pre-defined ones.

I saw this post: [How to add custom C++ keywords to be recognized by Minted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/how-to-add-custom-c-keywords-to-be-recognized-by-minted) but the solution is too difficult for me, and I don't even know if I could do such a thing in ShareLaTeX.

I tried with a workaround, but it's not convenient, because I have to correct the code and not simply cut and paste it from the SAS editor.

So, I decided to try with `listings`. I'm almost there but I don't manage to have my style `\color{green}\ttfamily` for comments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\newcommand{\saskeyword}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newenvironment{sasminted}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,fontsize=\small,baselinestretch=1, samepage=true]{sas}}
 {\end{minted}}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{% 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\bfseries,
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[s]{*}{;},
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[n]{*}{;},
    escapechar=|,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true,
    sensitive=false,
    otherkeywords={*,/},
}

\newenvironment{saslst}{\VerbatimEnvironment\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{lstlisting}}
 {\end{lstlisting}\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\noindent Pure \texttt{minted}:
\begin{sasminted}
/* comment */
data pippo; |\emph{within escape chars}|
set  pluto (firstobs=10 obs=14);
keep paperino;
minnie='a string';
* another comment;
run;
\end{sasminted}
This is what I would like to have (without my workaround):
\begin{sasminted}
/* comment */
data pippo; |\emph{within escape chars}|
set  pluto (|\saskeyword{firstobs}|=10 |\saskeyword{obs}|=14); 
keep paperino; 
minnie='a string';
* another comment;
run;
\end{sasminted}

\noindent with \texttt{listing}: 

\begin{lstlisting}
/* comment */
data pippo; |\emph{within escape chars}|
set  pluto (firstobs=10 obs=14);
keep paperino; 
minnie='a string';
* another comment;
run;
\end{lstlisting}
\noindent\texttt{minted} also recognizes when the \texttt{*} has to be put in black or in green:
\begin{sasminted}
/* this with minted */
proc freq data = pippo; 
tables pluto * paperino; 
run;
* another comment;
\end{sasminted}

\noindent I prefer minted highlighting also here: 

\begin{lstlisting}
/* this with listings */
proc freq data = pippo; 
tables pluto * paperino; 
run;
* another comment;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessting the issue comes as SAS in listings defineds ``/`` and ``*`` as keywords (see `lstlang3.sty`), the short rules often comes first. So we probably have to get more sneaky. It is a bit sad that those the  who made the SAS setup, did not include the comment stuff for SAS

Comment: @daleif is completely correct. I don't know SAS syntax but if you copy the language definition into your document using `\lstdefinelanguage` and remove `*` and `/` from the list of keywords, your comments come out green.

Comment: @AlanMunn isn't there something we can do about the order? I think it just have to have hte longer ones defined first.

Comment: May be offtopic: But the text "another comment" has to be in `//` and not `*` in c++

Comment: @koleygr My language is SAS, not C++, I added the post only because it explains how to add new keywords in `minted`.

Comment: Ok... So: forget the "may be" on my comment :P (I didn't knew that SAS is a language and had not understand)

Comment: Best solution, probably, since one cannot delete something from `otherkeywords` is the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186095/3929, aka `otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,\&,_,<,>=,=<,>},% removed *,/`

Comment: What exactly are the comment rules in SAS? I've written a code formatting package (on top of listings, but have no knowledge of the SAS syntax). Is `*` also used as the multiplication operator, or is is just like `%` in latex? Because, if it is the latter, then `*` probably should not be in `otherkeywords`

Comment: @daleif The comment are within `/* ... */` or from the `*` to the first `;`. The first is usually used to comment a piece of code (one or more steps), the second one to comment a single instruction (statement), since all the SAS instructions end with `;`.

Comment: @daleif `*` is used also as operator, not only for multiplication, example: `proc freq data = pippo;
tables pluto * paperino;
run;`

Comment: @CarLaTeX then how does SAS know that `* paperino;` is not an error? Probably symantics. I don't think listings can tell the difference (not sure if minted can either)

Comment: @daleif It's semantic, but `minted` does it, see my MWE... and when the `*` is after `tables` is black (in `minted`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem lies with the `otherkeywords` definition of the SAS language definition, which defines both `*` and `/` as keywords.  This overrides their use as comment markers.

Since there is no `deleteotherkeywords` macro, the simplest way to solve this is to overwrite the list of `otherkeywords` with those two characters removed. But since `*` is also used as the multiplication operator in SAS, doing this alone, will cause lines with `*` in them to appear as comments from the `*` onwards, since you have defined `*...;` as a delimited comment.

The way around this problem is to remove that definition of a comment and instead define `*` to be a comment only when it appears in column 1 using the `[f]` type for the comment definition.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{% 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\bfseries,
    columns=flexible,
    language=SAS,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morecomment=[f]{*},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},  
    escapechar=|,
    otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,\&,_,<,>=,=<,>},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true,
    sensitive=false,
}

\newenvironment{saslst}{\VerbatimEnvironment\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{lstlisting}}
 {\end{lstlisting}\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\noindent
With \texttt{listings}:

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% I don't want to break my listing across pages
\begin{lstlisting}
/* comment */
data pippo; |\emph{within escape chars}|
set  pluto (firstobs=10 obs=14);
keep paperino; 
pippo = pippo*pippo;
minnie='a string';
* another comment;
run;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]